# Will a man acquire orbit if we suppose Earth is rotating fast enough?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, estimation, earth

if we consider that the rotation of earth is mush faster (30000km/h),  so if a man standing on earth jumps 1 meter above will it acquire orbit if we ignore atmospheric friction

Comment: when u jump in a moving bus u land at the same place cause ur moving with the same velocity as the bus so relative velocity between u and bus is 0,  Same goes for earth no matter how fast the earth is moving u will stay on ground as ur will also be moving with same velocity

Comment: Yes, if the earth spun fast enough, the centrifugal force of the rotation would be strong enough to overcome gravity. In that case people (and things) near the equator would spontaneously flow away from the surface - no jumping required.

Comment: @shardul we always launch rockets to eastward direction to take benifot of earth's rotation (1670 km/h) , the same way if i supposes that earth is rotating much faster then what would happen

Comment: Given the guy jumps on equator strictly vertically, he must reach geostationary orbit. It can be 1 meter orbit, if Earth rotates fast enough.

Comment: This question needs details or clarity only to convert it to math problem. But this is physics forum, and the question is good enough as is. Yet another closed good question.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a circular orbit you need to accelerate with exactly
$$a=\frac{v^2}r$$
towards the center. For a circular orbit one can show that $v=2\pi fr$ where $f$ is the frequency in orbits per second. This gives
$$a=(2\pi f)^2r$$
The acceleration due to gravity is given by
$$a=\frac{GM}{r^2}.$$
Let's assume the person is standing at the equator. In that case $r$ is just the radius of the earth. We can now equate the two expressions for the accelerations to get
$$f=\frac{\sqrt{GM}}{(2\pi)^2r}.$$
Now, plugging in the mass and the radius of the earth gives a frequency of about $0.0001976$ Hz, which means the earth rotates with a period of about 1 hour and 24 minutes.

Note that at this rotation speed you don't need to jump to achieve orbit. Once you achieve the same velocity as the ground, you will be orbiting. Note that near the equator, everything which is not attached solidly to the ground will start floating. This includes bodies of water and sand.